# How to get data from XML in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, xml-parsing

I created class for getting data from XML format but it return data multiples times where is wrong? actually i want to only two tag **`en`** and **`ur`** not other.
My Data on Server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<words>
   <word wid="373012">
      <en>DOCTOR (Noun)</en>
      <ur>حکیم </ur>
   </word>
   <word wid="356630">
      <en>DOCTOR (Verb)</en>
      <ur>بدلنا </ur>
   </word>
   <word wid="356633">
      <en>DOCTOR (Verb)</en>
      <ur>بدلنا  دھوکا  دینا  ۔</ur>
   </word>
   <word wid="329801">
      <en>DOCTOR</en>
      <ur>ڈاکٹر  معالج  ۔</ur>
   </word>
   <word wid="364114">
      <en>DOCTOR</en>
      <ur>اُستاد </ur>
   </word>
   <word wid="190805">
      <en>DOCTOR (Verb)</en>
      <ur>ڈاکٹر بنانا  ۔</ur>
   </word>
</words>
```

java code for reverting list and XML parsing

```
try {
        ArrayList<UEDWord> list = null;
        URL URL = new URL(stringURL);
        XMLReader mXMLReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        mXMLReader.setContentHandler(new MXMLHandler());
        mXMLReader.parse(new InputSource(URL.openStream()));
        list = MXMLHandler.getSearchResults();
        return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

//

```
public class MXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public static ArrayList<UEDWord> SearchResults = new ArrayList<UEDWord>();
    String LastEngWord = "";
    String LastUrduWord = "";
    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;

    public MXMLHandler() {
        SearchResults.clear();
    }

    public static ArrayList<UEDWord> getSearchResults() {
        return SearchResults;
    }

    public void characters(char[] characters, int position, int noOfChar) throws SAXException {
        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(characters, position, noOfChar);
            currentElement = false;
        }
    }

    public void startElement(String URI, String localname, String qualifiedname, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        currentElement = true;
    }

    public void endElement(String URI, String localname, String qualifiedname) throws SAXException {
        currentElement = false;

        if (localname.equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
            LastEngWord = currentValue;
        // do {
        if (localname.equalsIgnoreCase("ur"))
            LastUrduWord = currentValue;
        // return;
        // } while (!localname.equalsIgnoreCase("word"));
        // Log.e(URI, localname + " " + qualifiedname);
        SearchResults.add(new UEDWord(LastEngWord, LastUrduWord));
    }
}
```

SetterGetter Class

```
public class UEDWord {
    private String EngWord;
    private String UrduWord;

    UEDWord(String EngWord, String UrduWord) {
        this.EngWord = EngWord;
        this.UrduWord = UrduWord;
    }

    public String getEngWord() {
        return this.EngWord;
    }

    public String getUrduWord() {
        return this.UrduWord;
    }

    public void setEngWord(String EngWord) {
        this.EngWord = EngWord;
    }

    public void setUrduWord(String UrduWord) {
        this.UrduWord = UrduWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why you don't you want to store these data in strings.xml with appropriate to your language postfixes?

Comment: So you say your Android app is pulling that XML file from the server and then parses it? Or is that XML built by your Android app and then sent to the server?

Comment: dear @MichaelSpitsin data is in on server, and data record is more 100000, it is not possible to store in string.xml

Comment: @LuigiPower i store data on phpmysql i provide word is in query  to database and it return data in such above form.

Comment: oh by the way, for booleans don't use the Boolean class. A native boolean should do the job. I will look into the problem now

Comment: Also, don't use capital initials in Java variables, please.

Comment: why down vote my question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think is happening:

Your parser reaches the 'en' element. Goes into the "startElement" method, sets "currentElement" to true, then goes into the "characters" method in which it loads the String, finally going into the "endElement" method in which the String is used to create a UEDWord.

At this point there is already an error: You're trying to create an UEDWord using EN and UR as it's parameters, but here you have only one of the two. Check if both are set before creating and adding the Word.

Going forward, your parser looks at the 'ur' element. Reads the content. Creates a new Word and adds it to your list (At this point, you created and added 2 Words instead of 1).

Now the parser goes on to see '/word', closing the 'word' element from before. So the endElement method is called, but the currentValue has never been reset, so a new UEDWord, the same as before, is created and added to the array.

In the end, you should have 13 excess words, if I got your problem correctly.

My advice is to check which element you found inside endElement and only add to the list if both your EN and UR words are ready to be added. After you added the values to the list, clear currentValue and LastEngWord, LastUrduWord, to be able to check them being null the next time.

This should work (As said in the comments, not tested):

```
public class MXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public static ArrayList<UEDWord> SearchResults = new ArrayList<UEDWord>();
    String LastEngWord = null;
    String LastUrduWord = null;
    boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;

    public MXMLHandler() {
        SearchResults.clear();
    }

    public static ArrayList<UEDWord> getSearchResults() {
        return SearchResults;
    }

    public void characters(char[] characters, int position, int noOfChar) throws SAXException {
        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(characters, position, noOfChar);
            currentElement = false;
        }
    }

    public void startElement(String URI, String localname, String qualifiedname, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        currentElement = true;
    }

    public void endElement(String URI, String localname, String qualifiedname) throws SAXException {
        currentElement = false;


        if (localname.equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
            LastEngWord = currentValue;
        else if (localname.equalsIgnoreCase("ur"))
            LastUrduWord = currentValue;

        if(LastEngWord != null && LastUrdWord != null)
        {
           SearchResults.add(new UEDWord(LastEngWord, LastUrduWord));
           LastEngWord = null;
           LastUrdWord = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can try editing the post with what I think should solve the problem, but I have no way of testing it. Should I write it anyway?

Comment: I update my question, now its more clear. please help me if you can.

Comment: Can you show me what is inside the "list" after "list = MXMLHandler.getSearchResults();"?

Comment: thanks now its works, that time only internet issue :)

Comment: Glad to be of help!